# Unable to stub out helper method

Tags: controller, mocking, helper, stub

I'm unable to stub out a helper method.
So, if I have:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

   include SessionsHelper
```

and I define my helper method in SessionsHelper:

```
class SessionsHelper
    def current_user
    .....
```

My attempt to stub it out below fails:

```
describe SessionsController do
    describe "when logged in" do

        before(:each) do
            @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
            controller.stub!(:current_user, @user)     
        end
```

This has no effect. Calling current_user returns nil.

Edit: (I originally thought that this problem only occurred when current_user resided in a different helper that got included, but I was wrong it seems. The problem seems broader than that.)